# PHP preg_match? How to return not matched characters?

Tags: php, preg-match, expression

Lets say i have:

```
$string = 'qwe1ASD@';

if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $string))
{
    echo 'OK';
}
else
{
    echo 'BAD';
}
```

Now, is there simple solution, to find all characters from $string which don't match expression? So in return, in place of "BAD" i want to have ex. "BAD. You can't use following characters: 1@"

Thanks in advance for any simple hints! :)

---

Thank you Floern, your answer suit best my needs. It have only one "preg" so it's also good for performance. Thank you again.
I implemented it for now as follw:

```
if(preg_match_all('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/s', $string, $forbidden))
{
    $forbidden = implode('', array_unique($forbidden[0]));

    echo 'BAD. Your string contains forbidden characters: '.htmlentities($forbidden).'';
}
```

Comment: You can add a general msg stating whats unacceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `preg_match_all()`:

```
if(preg_match_all('/[^a-zA-Z]/s', $string, $matches)){
    var_dump($matches); // BAD
}
else{
    echo 'OK';
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer, now I know what specific character/s are matched.

Answer (score 4):

```
$tmpstring=preg_replace('~[A-Za-z]~','',$string);
if(strlen($tmpstring))
    //bad chars: $tmpstring
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'qwe1ASD@';

if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $string))
{
    echo 'OK';
}
else
{
    echo 'BAD.  You cannot use the following characters: ' + preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z]/', '', $string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways. I find this one nice:

```
$check = preg_prelace('/[a-zA-Z]/', '', $string);

if ($check) echo 'BAD ' . $check;
```

UPDATE:

```
if (strlen($check)) echo 'BAD ' . $check;
```

Comment: Since the update not any longer since. However, this is not part of the question: How to check if a string is empty.